# Missing printers in wx.PrintDialog

Tags: python, printing, wxpython, xubuntu

We are finally migrating our old workstations with Xubuntu 9.04 to
Xubuntu 10.04, and in the process we're testing our in-house wxPython
application on the new systems.
Everything works nicely, except that `wx.PrintDialog`'s popup shows NO
printers available, there's only a "Default printer" with empty
"Device" and "Status". This happens even with wxPython's PrintDialog
demo. What could I check out?

(Xubuntu 10.04, wxPython 2.8.10.1)

Comment: Erm, available printers in the system?

Comment: There are 3 physical printers and the PDF one

Comment: Have you checked the print dialogs in other applications like Firefox or Evince?

Comment: Evince shows the printers correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have to install libgnomeprintui:

`apt-get install libgnomeprintui2.2-0`

(found [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/wx-users/PRCaxobcZG4/DZgFZlZab9gJ))